# stackblitz Can't find package ....what exactly stackblitz trying to do when pkg name is capitalized by mistake

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tried React Redux on stackbliz , encountered this error "can't find package redux" when i wrongly capitalized pkg name in one of imports. Screen shot below with both fix, error causing statement. Any body explain , what exactly stackbliz trying to do here. [image]

Comment: Try reinstalling your dependencies after cleaning cache

Comment: thanks for your comment. It works with all-lower pkg name. Trying to understand why stackbliz error message is not "can't find pakcage Redux (capitalized)" instead.  misleading error message. I see multiple forum raised similar issues.  In my case the fix is not relative path import issue.  Its wrong pkg name - captalized.